# Typo3 v10 image metadata translation issue

Tags: image, typo3, metadata, translation, typoscript

I'm developing a multi language website with Typo3 v10.4.32.
Everything works fine. Except image metadata translation feature.

I uploaded an image, and I added translation for metadata (German is default)

[image: Image metadata]

After then I added page translation. In backend I see that images have default language metadata in both languages

[image: Image in content element]

If I click the image element to edit I see the correct behaviour: Typo3 is aware that the image has translation of metadata

[image: Translation data as expected]

In frontend unfortunately I see the problem: the default language metadata is shown

[image: Frontend]

Typoscript template is simple:

```
config {
    linkVars = L
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = 1
    sys_language_softExclude = tt_content:image
    sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:image
    sys_language_uid = 0
}

# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!

page.20 = CONTENT
page.20.table = tt_content
page.20.select {
    orderBy = sorting
    where = {#colPos} = 0
}
[siteLanguage("languageId") == 1]
    config.sys_language_uid = 1
    config.htmlTag_langKey = en
    config.language = en
    config.locale_all = en_US
[end]
```

Is the code below necessary ? since it is configured in yaml file

```
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_US
```

I could add translation in content elements, but images are supposed to be used in many places, so it becomes annoying to add the same text

I tried to search a solution, but I found very old similar issue with Typo3 v7 and the issue was supposed to be fixed in the next version Typo3 v8.

I suppose that the problem does not connect to NGINX ?

Maybe I need to add some code in LocalConfiguration ?

Comment: Probably related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95811

Comment: Thank you! It's strange that such important feature did not fixed yet ?